# How to use browsedDeviceTypeMask property in Swift 2

Tags: swift2, imagekit

In the past (Objective-C) I can use browsedDeviceTypeMask property like this:

```
 mDeviceBrowser.browsedDeviceTypeMask = ICDeviceLocationTypeMaskLocal|ICDeviceLocationTypeMaskRemote|ICDeviceTypeMaskScanner
```

I converted it to:

```
 mDeviceBrowser.browsedDeviceTypeMask = ICDeviceLocationTypeMask.Local | ICDeviceLocationTypeMask.Shared | ICDeviceLocationTypeMask.Bluetooth | ICDeviceLocationTypeMask.Bonjour
```

But I got error message:

```
Binary Operator '|' cannot be applied to tow 'ICDeviceLocationTypeMask' operands
```

Any help to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

This is the syntax for Swift 2:

```
mDeviceBrowser.browsedDeviceTypeMask = ICDeviceTypeMask(rawValue:
   ICDeviceLocationTypeMask.Local.rawValue |
   ICDeviceLocationTypeMask.Shared.rawValue |
   ICDeviceLocationTypeMask.Bonjour.rawValue |
   ICDeviceLocationTypeMask.Bluetooth.rawValue)!;
```